# bootstrap-star-rating V4.1.0 not working with Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to use the bootstrap-star rating v4.1.0 here https://npm.io/package/bootstrap-star-rating but in my case It does not work.

In index.html I have added the following libraries

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>My_APP</title>
  <base href="/" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <!-- with v4.1.0 Krajee SVG theme is used as default (and must be loaded as below) - include any of the other theme CSS files as mentioned below (and change the theme property of the plugin) -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating@4.1.0/themes/krajee-svg/theme.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
  <!-- important mandatory libraries -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating@4.1.0/js/star-rating.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!-- with v4.1.0 Krajee SVG theme is used as default (and must be loaded as below) - include any of the other theme JS files as mentioned below (and change the theme property of the plugin) -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating@4.1.0/themes/krajee-svg/theme.js"></script>

  <!-- optionally if you need translation for your language then include locale file as mentioned below (replace LANG.js with your own locale file) -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating@4.1.0/js/locales/LANG.js"></script>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>

</body>
</html>
```

Then in my component supplier-details.component.html I have added the following line and the jquery code like this.

```
<div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
  <label for="eval_disponibilidad">Availability Evaluation</label>
  <input id="input-id" type="text" class="rating" max="5" value="1">
</div>

<script>
  $("#input-id").rating({ 'size': 'sm' });
</script>
```

Yet visually the input field is still there and there are 10 start five filled and five empty stars as you can see in my picture .
[image: 10 starts]

Why am I having this issue thank you for your help.

Do I need to add code in the supplierDetailsComponent ? here?

```
export class SupplierDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  public supplier: Supplier;
  public supplierId: number;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Also as you can see in my package.json file I have added the following  important libraries like so.

```
"bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
"bootstrap-star-rating": "^4.1.0",
"jquery": "^3.6.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating DOM manually and using Angular is strongly advised against it. Even if you would manage to solve the current issue, there is a good chance you would encounter other issues. It would be way more reliable to use one of the existing Angular ports of bootstrap. For example, there is [a rating component in the ng-bootstrap library](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/rating/examples).

Comment: Yes but I really like the css style of the bootstrap-star rating is there a way that I can have  the same style with a  rating component?

Comment: sure. it would require some reverse engineering to extract styles from the bootstrap-star rating and some research of ng-bootstrap docs. I'm 100% sure it would be more fruitful than making friends of jQuery and Angular